# Does query string case affect SEO?

Tags: seo, query-string, case-sensitive

Our team is working on how to handle query strings. Does it matter in terms of SEO whether we use **pascal case**, **camel case** or **kebab case**? Which is best?

`https://example.com/page?dealType=m&propertyType=sample`
or

`https://example.com/page?DealType=m&PropertyType=sample`
or

`https://example.com/page?deal-type=m&property-type=sample`

Answer (score 4):

It does not matter, but you must be consistent, as all three examples you showed represent different URLs to be indexed.

Some like to stick to lowercase as it reduces the possibility of human error when manually typing in a URL. Kebab case can also make it easier for humans to read.